# ASP.NET MVC Edit CheckBoxList values in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble understanding how to retrieve and edit the DevId values from my CustomerDevice table in my database to the CheckBoxList based on the CustId value.

My Index Action Method for the CustomerDeviceController displays a list of Customers from my Customers table. I have an ActionLink labeled "Edit" that passes the CustId value to the CustomerDeviceController [HttpGet] Edit(int? id) Action Method which currently displays all CheckBoxListItem values from the Devices table. However, the CheckBoxList does not display the checked DevId values from the CustomerDevice table in the database to the CheckBoxList that pertain to the CustId, instead it displays a check for each of the CheckBoxList values.

The part that I'm having trouble understanding and figuring out, is how can I display the selected DevId values from the CustomerDevice table in my database to the CheckBoxList based on the CustId and then Edit/Update the modified CheckBoxListItems on the [HttpPost] Edit Action Method back to my CustomerDevice table in my database if need be.

Please see the following code below that I have so far.

**Models**

```
public class CheckBoxListItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string CustDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string CustFirstName { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class Device
{
    public int DevId { get; set; }
    public string DevType { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDevice
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public int DevId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModels**

```
public class CustomerDeviceFormViewModel
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string CustDisplayName { get; set; }
    public List<CheckBoxListItem> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerDeviceController**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var customervm = new CustomerDeviceFormViewModel();
    Customer customer = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    customervm.CustId = customer.CustId;
    customervm.CustDisplayName = customer.CustDisplayName;
    // Retrieves list of Devices for CheckBoxList
    var deviceList = db.Devices.ToList();
    var checkBoxListItems = new List<CheckBoxListItem>();
    foreach (var device in deviceList)
    {
        checkBoxListItems.Add(new CheckBoxListItem()
        {
            ID = device.DevId,
            Display = device.DevType,
            IsChecked = deviceList.Where(x => x.DevId == device.DevId).Any()
        });
    }
    customervm.Devices = checkBoxListItems;
    return View(customervm);
}

        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(CustomerDeviceFormViewModel vmEdit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Customer customer = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == vmEdit.CustId);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            foreach (var deviceId in vmEdit.Devices.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ID))
            {
                var customerDevices = new CustomerDevice
                {
                    CustId = vmEdit.CustId,
                    DevId = deviceId
                };

                db.Entry(customerDevices).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(vmEdit);
    }
```

**Edit.chtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
    Please select the Devices to assign to <b>@Html.DisplayFor(c => c.CustDisplayName)</b>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Devices)
</div>

@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.CustId)

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**Shared/EditorTemplate/CheckBoxListItem.chtml**

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsChecked)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsChecked, Model.Display)
</label>
<br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for setting the `IsChecked` value will always return `true` (your loop is basically say *if the collection contains me (which of course it does) then set it to true*).

You need to get the selected values for each `Customer` by reading the values from your `CustomerDevice` table

```
Customer customer = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);
if (customer == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}
// Get all devices
var deviceList = db.Devices.ToList();
// Get the selected device ID's for the customer
IEnumerable<int> selectedDevices = db.CustomerDevices
    .Where(x => x.CustId == id).Select(x => x.DevId);
// Build view model
var model = new CustomerDeviceFormViewModel()
{
    CustId = customer.CustId,
    CustDisplayName = customer.CustDisplayName,
    Devices = deviceList.Select(x => new CheckBoxListItem()
    {
        ID = x.DevId,
        Display = x.DevType,
        IsChecked = selectedDevices.Contains(x.DevId)
    }).ToList()
};
return View(model);
```

Comment: when I copy/paste your solution it says that I'm missing `} expected`. Is this line of code `IEnumerable<int> selectedDevices = db.CustomerDevices.Where(x => x.CustId == id).Select(x => x.DevId);` just creating an **int array** to the variable **selectedDevices**?

Comment: See edit (2nd last line was missing `;`). And yes, `selectedDevices` is a collection containing just the `DevId` values

Comment: thank you!  I got another error message but found the fix for it. I modified `var deviceList = db.Devices;` to `var deviceList = db.Devices.ToList();`

Comment: Is it still not working? (I can create a simple fiddle for you to show how it works if your still having problems)

Comment: it is working fine now. Just need to figure out the [HttpPost] Edit Action Method now for updating the DevId values if need be.

Comment: You just get then using `var selected = model.Devices.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Id);`

Comment: I'm not sure were to add `var selected = model.Devices.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Id);` at in my [HttpPost] Edit Action Method. I edited my original post to show you what I currently have for my [HttpPost] Edit Action Method.

Comment: No, You first need to delete the existing `CustomerDevice`'s for the customer and then add the 'new' ones. I'll update the answer shortly

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!! I would truly appreciate you helping me with the last part when you can.

Comment: I added the code you supplied for the POST but I'm now getting the error message. **An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code**

Comment: **Additional information: The instance of entity type 'CustomerDevice' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked.**

Comment: **When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.**

Comment: Are you using EF6 (you need that for the `RemoveRange()` method - otherwise just remove each one in a loop. And call `SaveChanges()` before adding the new ones

Comment: No, I'm using Entity Framework Core. I'm not sure how to remove each one in a loop :( Could you please assist me with this last step, so close.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of Razor code that I've used:

```
   foreach (SelectListItem p in Model.PositionList)
    {
    @Html.Raw(p.Text + "<input type=checkbox name=\"PositionIDs\" id=\"PositionIDs\" value=" + @p.Value + (Model.Positions != null && Model.Positions.Any(pos => pos.ScoreCardId == Convert.ToInt32(p.Value)) ? " checked />" : " />"));
    }
```

Comment: I think my problem may be in the CustomerDeviceController rather than in the View.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to have a look at the MvcCheckBoxList NuGet package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcCheckBoxList/

This makes doing some powerful stuff with a CheckBoxList much easier in MVC - and may be a better approach to fixing your CheckBox issues.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14152900)

Comment: @OrDuan I do generally agree with your sentiment, and if I had a specific piece of code to fix a specific issue I would include it. However, as this is a NuGet package explaining its full workings in the answer may be a bit excessive?

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's question which is about how to correctly set the values of the checkboxes based on data in the database

Comment: I disagree - using this tool may enable the OP to do that in a better way - it's how I found out about this package and I was grateful. It's the kind of thing you don't think about if you don't know about it. It is an alternative way to fix the OP's problem.

Comment: OP's code for generating the html is fine. The question is about how to get the correct data from the database and using a different tool for generating the html does absolutely nothing to solve the problem.

Comment: "How do I do X with Y" "Did you know if you use Z it's much easier". That kind of answer has hugely changed my approach to certain problems for the better in the past - and I think should be encouraged. Strategy v Tactics.  It may help the OP better solve their problem - which is what this site is for.

Comment: Not only is this just your opinion, it's not an answer to the question. If you want, add the link as a comment, not in the answer section (which id for answers to the question)

Comment: All answers are opinions. It does answer the question by approaching it from a different angle - the specifics aren't important once you do that.  "How long would it take me to drive to Argentina?" "Have you considered flying" "I didn't know that was an option, thanks". You can live in your ground-bound world. I like the option of flying myself. Let's agree to disagree.